# How can I figure out where my base is after dying in Minecraft: Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Unfortunately I died, and spawned in a weird place.

How do figure out where I am, and get back to where I was? I don't know how to spawn in the right place, by my bed?

Answer (score 1):

Because unlike Minecraft for the PC (which has debugging tools; F3), Pocket Edition does not have any sense of mapping or 'way' you can actually find out where you are.

So, because of this... If you find yourself not spawning in a bed or close to your settlement... Then there's nothing you can do to find your settlement.  The only thing I can suggest is:
**Settle somewhere else, or explore (again); who knows - You may find your old settlement; base again.**

If you have made your base close to your first spawn-point, you may want to try getting a [compass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Compass) (if Pocket Edition has one) and follow it to your spawn-point.

---

You may want to try out [this tutorial](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-discussion/1963377-the-official-minecraft-pocket-edition-re-texture) which outlines how to put your Pocket Edition world into MCEdit on your computer.
(Just scroll down to the second part of the post.)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create a compass and follow it to your original spawn. This only works if your house is near your original spawn point, or if you were on a bed before you died inside or near your house. The same thing happened to me when I died underwater in pocket edition 0.10.0 and I had to mine redstone and iron into a compass and follow it home.

Comment: It depends on which update PE is on. In the PC edition (currently on version 1.8) the compass will no longer point to the bed spawn, but rather to the original world spawn.

Answer (score -1):

It just happened to me and I died with my diamonds and some obsidian, even though I have a bed and my spawn point is right next to it. For some reason, even on creative, once you make a bed it will not spawn you next to it but about 50 chunks away. The only way to get back is with a compass